# What is the view when using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My understanding is that the Web API is the controller -- since it falls between the AngularJS application and the model -- and the AngularJS application is the view. But the AngularJS application has its own model (the Web API), view (the markup) and controller (connects the API and the view). Am I missing something here?

Comment: WebAPI isn't really a "controller", it is more of an interface library.  It is actually possible for an ASP.Net MVC Controller to access a WebAPI resource, though this seems to be rarely used.  As far as ASP.Net MVC is concerned, the view is really the container for the AngularJS application;  whether or not it uses a Controller or not and manipulates it's own Model to manipulate the area around Angular has no real effect on Angular itself.  However, if ASP.Net MVC delivers a new *page*, the new page has an entirely new AngularJS App.

Answer (score 0):

For a single page application I will have a 1 controller home with one action named index that will provide the "index.html" page. this is the main page of the app where all initial resources from server are inked to, such as CSS bundle and JS.
The rest I will leave to ControllerAPI and angular. so template I will write as pure html that later can be bundled inside the js. and all communication will be restAPI for json data from the ControllerAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two concepts:

1. Angularjs with MVC
2. Angularjs with WebApi

   For client side, we use `angularjs` and for server side happenings. we use `Webapi` or `MVC`. We usually use `WebApi` with `angularjs` and it is always recommended.`Webapi` doesn't have views ,it only handles server side data. we manage that data on client side using `angularjs`

Now coming to your question:-
`View` is basically used to make a visual interface for user.it has same definition in `angularjs` as well as `MVC`.

`Webapi` is not a controller.it is used to handle server side happening.
it works as a backend.
it doesn't works as model in `angularjs`.
`Angularjs` has it's own modal which is called `$scope`.

So you can't mix both Webapi as well as angularjs.
both are different, one works on client side other on server side.

hope this will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

A **View** is basically what controllers return.

In case of ASP.NET Web Api, the View will be the JSON data returned. In case of ASP.NET MVC usually is Html code. However, you can use ASP.NET MVC to return JSON Data and mimics the same behaviour that exists for Web Api.

ASP.NET MVC uses *System.Web.Http* and Web Api uses *System.Net.Http*, and both are based in MVC pattern. So in both cases there exist Views.

In my opinion the name of "View" folder in the ASP.NET MVC framework template leads to confusion. The lack of "View" folder doesn't change the pattern MVC of Web Api.